# deviceready event not firing in embedded Cordova

Tags: cordova

I embed codova-webview followed [this guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html), my app can successfully launch, codova-webview can successfully display, but deviceready event didn't fired. what's wrong?

version of Cordova is latest so far. (5.4.1)

Comment: r u loading cordova.js in your CDVWebView startPage html?

Comment: yes, i have loaded cordova.js. i found that this error only happened when integrating codova-webview just with my old xcode project. When integrate with a new xcode project, deviceready event can be fired successfullly

Comment: Not sure what the difference may be between your 'old' and 'new' xcode projects. If your old project used an earlier version of Cordova, there could  be some issues in how you are 'upgrading'. You may just want to port your code to the new project.

Comment: thank you, i retry and it is successful, so strange....